# Script to calculate width, and either resize, show, or hide HTML menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a script that handles the responsive liabilities of my HTML menu. The menu will have a variable amount of `<li class="menu-item">`, resulting in a variable total width. I have 3 functions.

This function is responsible for looping through each `li` element and calculating the greatest width of the set of elements.

```
function resize_menu() {

    var maxWidth = -1;

    $(".menu-item").each(function() {
        maxWidth = maxWidth > $(this).width() ? maxWidth : $(this).width();
    });

    $(".menu-item").each(function() {
        $(this).width(maxWidth);
    }); 
}
```

This function is responsible for displaying the mobile menu, and hiding the standard menu.

```
function mobile_menu() {
    $("#mobile-menu").css("display", "block");

    $(".menu-primary-menu-container").css("display", "none");
}
```

This function is responsible for showing the standard menu, and hiding the mobile menu, invert of the above.

```
function show_menu() {
    $("#mobile-menu").css("display", "none");

    $(".menu-primary-menu-container").css("display", "initial");
}
```

Now to execute functions above, I have created instances in which they need to be fired.

```
$( window ).load(function() {
    //declare variables
    var resizeTimer;
    var maxWidth = -1;
    var count = $(".menu-item").length;

    // Loop menu items, and retrieve greatest width, to be multiplied by count
    $(".menu-item").each(function() {
        maxWidth = maxWidth > $(this).width() ? maxWidth : $(this).width();
    });

    // Only resize li elements if screen width is greater than menu width
    if ($(window).width() > maxWidth * count) {
        resize_menu();  
    } else {
    // or else show the mobile menu
        mobile_menu();
    };

    // On a resize (delayed for performance)
    $(window).on('resize', function(e) {
        clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
        resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            // again, if window is less than menu, show mobile 
            if ($(window).width() < maxWidth * count) {
                mobile_menu();
            } else {
            // or else, show regular menu
            // Note: resize, incase screen was loaded smaller than menu 
                resize_menu();
                show_menu();
            };  
        }, 50);
    });

    // if the mobile menu icon is clicked, show menu
    $("#mobile-menu").click(function() {
        show_menu();
    });
});
```

This code does work, however there are some performance issues. When I resize the window, some times the hiding of the regular menu, and showing of the mobile is delayed, caused probably by the timeout I set, is it worth getting rid of? Also, I know this code is wet, lots of repetition. I could use advice on that. Finally, how can I store my selectors in variables and use them throughout the script?

Comment: What does the standard menu look like?  What does the mobile menu look like? Are the list items arranged vertically or horizontally?

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: The [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) method is shorter than [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, $(this).width());
maxWidth = maxWidth > $(this).width() ? maxWidth : $(this).width();
```